# jQuery Inputmask Plugin prevents form from submitting when a masked field has the "readonly" attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, form-submit, preventdefault, jquery-inputmask

I am using this jQuery Plugin https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask to enable inputfield masking.

In some forms I have to display readonly fields which also have a mask applied to them. This however prevents the form from being submitted via jQuery `$("#form").submit()`. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this...

```js
$('[data-inputmask]').inputmask();

$('#send').click(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});
  
$('#send2').click(function() {
    $('#form2').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask@5.0.6-beta.12/dist/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>

<h4>Won't submit (includes readonly field)</h4>
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input readonly type="text" name="test" data-inputmask="'alias' : 'decimal'" value="123">
</form>
<button id="send">send</button>

<h4>Works fine:</h4>
<form id="form2" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test" data-inputmask="'alias' : 'decimal'" value="123">
</form>
<button id="send2">send</button>
```

I think I narrowed the problem down to this piece of code in the inputmask plugin. It looks as if the default event (submit) is prevented in case the form has a readOnly field:

```
 var EventRuler = {
        on: function on(input, eventName, eventHandler) {
            var $ = input.inputmask.dependencyLib, ev = function ev(e) {
                e.originalEvent && (e = e.originalEvent || e, arguments[0] = e);
                var that = this, args, inputmask = that.inputmask, opts = inputmask ? inputmask.opts : void 0;
                if (void 0 === inputmask && "FORM" !== this.nodeName) {
                    var imOpts = $.data(that, "_inputmask_opts");
                    $(that).off(), imOpts && new _inputmask.default(imOpts).mask(that);
                } else {
                    if ("setvalue" === e.type || "FORM" === this.nodeName || !(that.disabled || that.readOnly && !("keydown" === e.type && e.ctrlKey && 67 === e.keyCode || !1 === opts.tabThrough && e.keyCode === _keycode.default.TAB))) {
                        switch (e.type) {
                            case "input":
                                if (!0 === inputmask.skipInputEvent || e.inputType && "insertCompositionText" === e.inputType) return inputmask.skipInputEvent = !1,
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                break;

                            case "keydown":
                                inputmask.skipKeyPressEvent = !1, inputmask.skipInputEvent = inputmask.isComposing = e.keyCode === _keycode.default.KEY_229;
                                break;

                            case "keyup":
                            case "compositionend":
                                inputmask.isComposing && (inputmask.skipInputEvent = !1);
                                break;

                            case "keypress":
                                if (!0 === inputmask.skipKeyPressEvent) return e.preventDefault();
                                inputmask.skipKeyPressEvent = !0;
                                break;

                            case "click":
                            case "focus":
                                return inputmask.validationEvent ? (inputmask.validationEvent = !1, input.blur(),
                                    (0, _inputHandling.HandleNativePlaceholder)(input, (inputmask.isRTL ? _positioning.getBufferTemplate.call(inputmask).slice().reverse() : _positioning.getBufferTemplate.call(inputmask)).join("")),
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        input.focus();
                                    }, 3e3)) : (args = arguments, setTimeout(function() {
                                    input.inputmask && eventHandler.apply(that, args);
                                }, 0)), !1;
                        }
                        var returnVal = eventHandler.apply(that, arguments);
                        return !1 === returnVal && (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation()), returnVal;
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            };
            input.inputmask.events[eventName] = input.inputmask.events[eventName] || [], input.inputmask.events[eventName].push(ev),
                [ "submit", "reset" ].includes(eventName) ? null !== input.form && $(input.form).on(eventName, ev.bind(input)) : $(input).on(eventName, ev);
        },
```

Edit: I would like to know if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I have had the same problem, but it also happens without using jQuery.submit() for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after spending `hours` i found out for **you** this is definitely as `bug` hence why you are experiencing this `issue`. I will be raising a `github` issue for this bug or if you want to do it let me know.

If you have a `form` which includes any `disabled` or `readonly` fields you can use `this script CDN` version of `inputmask` There is no difference between `4.0` and `5.0` version all the features are same. All yours forms will be submitted normally with all `input mask` working.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('[data-inputmask]').inputmask();

$('#send').click(function() {
  $('#form').submit();
});

$('#send2').click(function() {
  $('#form2').submit();
});

$('#send3').click(function() {
  $('#form2').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/4.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<h4>Will submit (includes readonly field)</h4>
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input readonly  type="text" name="test" data-inputmask="'alias' : 'decimal'" value="123">
</form>
<button id="send">send</button>

<h4>Will submit (includes disabled field)</h4>
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input disabled  type="text" name="test" data-inputmask="'alias' : 'decimal'" value="123">
</form>
<button id="send3">send</button>

<h4>Works fine:</h4>
<form id="form2" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test" data-inputmask="'alias' : 'decimal'" value="123">
</form>
<button id="send2">send</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that still experiences this problem: The issue was fixed in version `5.0.6-beta.15`.

Answer (score 1):

On pressing the button just remove the `readonly` attribute

```
     $("#send").click(function (e) {
          $("[data-inputmask]").removeAttr("readonly");
          $("#form").submit();
        });
```

Shown to be working here https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-minsky-dp7ej?file=/index.html:1101-1237

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this kind of lazy hack can not be the solution to the problem. I would like to know if this is a bug in the inputmask library or if I am doing something wrong in using it.

Comment: I guess I could have asked the question more specifically.

Comment: Original question:
".This however prevents the form from being submitted via jQuery $("#form").submit(). I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this..."
The github readme / issue you & others posted has no response for the preventDefault, blame => https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blame/5.x/lib/eventruler.js 

The "lazy hack" solves your issue, in the absence of reasoning, you can fork or work around the issue.

One thing you should wonder is why an entire form with a single readonly input would need to be submitted - Add a "continue" link

Best of luck!

Comment: This was just an example form to illustrate the problem. The actual forms contain a lot more fields. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If they are all readonly, the user has no input - So use a simple button to forward them,. If they are a mix of readonly and editable fields  and you wish to use this library, the "hack" lets you proceed - I cannot see a reasoning why they add it.